# Action bar style theme generator theme not getting applied

Tags: android

So I used the action bar style generator to create a theme with style compatibility mode set to `AppCompat`. I downloaded the `ZIP` file and copy and pasted all the files inside my folder but the theme isn't showing up when emulator is ran.

The `styles_actionstyle.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <resources>

  <style name="Theme.Actionstyle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item  name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_actionstyle</item      >
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Actionstyle</item>
    <item  name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Actionstyle</item>
    <item  name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Actionstyle</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Actionstyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Actionstyle</item>
    <item   name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_actionstyle</item>
    <item  name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_actionstyle</item>
    <item  name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Actionstyle</item>


    <!-- Light.DarkActionBar specific -->
    <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.Actionstyle.Widget</item>

   </style>

   <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Actionstyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_actionstyle</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_actionstyle</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_actionstyle</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Actionstyle</item>
   </style>

 <style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Actionstyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_transparent_actionstyle</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Actionstyle</item>
 </style>

<style name="PopupMenu.Actionstyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu"> 
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_actionstyle</item>   
</style>

<style name="DropDownListView.Actionstyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_actionstyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Actionstyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_actionstyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownNav.Actionstyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_actionstyle</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_actionstyle</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_actionstyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ProgressBar.Actionstyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_actionstyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Actionstyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_actionstyle</item>
 </style>

<!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
<style name="Theme.Actionstyle.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Actionstyle</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Actionstyle</item>
</style>

 </resources>
```

The V14 version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <resources>

  <style name="Theme.Actionstyle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_actionstyle</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Actionstyle</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Actionstyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Actionstyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Actionstyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Actionstyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_actionstyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_actionstyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Actionstyle</item>

            <!-- Light.DarkActionBar specific -->
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.Actionstyle.Widget</item>

  </style>

  <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Actionstyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_background_textured_actionstyle</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_actionstyle</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_background_textured_actionstyle</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Actionstyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Actionstyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_transparent_actionstyle</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Actionstyle</item>
</style>

<!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
<style name="Theme.Actionstyle.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Actionstyle</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Actionstyle</item>
</style>

 </resources>
```

The manifests file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mycompany.blooddonation2" >
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Actionstyle" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by extending my main activity with 'Activity' class instead of 'ActionBarActivity' class.